# Codimension 2 foliations on simply connected 4-manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, anosov-systems, foliations

Are there examples of codimension 2 foliations on simply connected compact 4-manifolds such that

- Every leaf is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$
- Every leaf is dense?

Same question for 5-manifolds and foliations of with leaves diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^3$.

I am trying to show absence of Anosov diffeos on simply connected 4 and 5 manifolds and I would like to make sure I am not missing any important foliation theory background. So relevant references will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean dimension 2 or codimension 2 ? Asking the leafs to be $\mathbb{R}^2$ tends to point toward the former.

Comment: @Benoit: I believe in his context, what he would like to know is if there is some obstruction to having two transversal foliations (one of dimension and one of codimension 2) whose leaves are $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ (or $\mathbb{R}^3$) with that properties. 

Comment: Sorry, I will edit the question. rpotrie: this would be the next question and I don't think this is possible, but probably very hard to show using topology only. 

Comment: for holomorphic foliations of complex surfaces, there is a classification of Brunella:
http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1474805
But you'd have to unravel the statement to see what it says in the simply-connected case. 